# How can I get XML Plaintext in DB2

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I am currently working on a DB2 native stored procedure, working on logging errors.  I am logging all of the errors that get raised on another table, and one of the things I am logging is what the stored procedure receives as its parameters.

On one particular stored procedure, one of the parameters is of the data type XML (IN P_FILTERS XML).. What I want to log in the error logging table is just the plaintext of the XML Document.

For example if I pass in XML that looks like this

```
<xml><Hello value='what is up'></Hello></xml>
```

I want to put

```
"<xml><Hello value='what is up'></Hello></xml>" as Varchar(200)
```

in the error logging table.

I have thouroughly researched this question and am unable to find anything.

I tried to do something like this, but couldn't get it to work

```
SET V_ERR_XML_TEXT = XMLCAST(XMLQUERY('$m/*'
    PASSING P_FILTERS AS "m" RETURNING SEQUENCE) AS VARCHAR(200));
```

Comment: _Couldn't get it to work_ how exactly?

Comment: Consider the `XMLSERIALIZE()` function.

Comment: I'm sorry I will specify, by "Couldn't get it to work," I meant that I was getting SQLCODE -16002: an xquery expression has an unexpected token token following text. expected tokens may include: token-list

Also I am  currently looking into XMLSERIALIZE() to see what I can come up with.

Comment: For anyone looking for the answer, I found it with the `XMLSERIALIZE()` It ended up being this 


`SET V_ERR_XML_TEXT = VARCHAR(XMLSERIALIZE(P_FILTERS AS CLOB)) ;`